# Why can't Flow tell that my object is an Immutable Map after checking with isMap()?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js, flowtype

I'm trying to work out why Flow gives an error here:

```
// @flow

import { Map } from 'immutable';

type Filemap = Map<string, Buffer>;
type FilemapCompatibleObject = Filemap | { [string]: Buffer };

export const castFilemap = (object: FilemapCompatibleObject): Filemap => {
  // checking with instanceof works fine
  if (object instanceof Map) {
    return object;
  }

  // checking with isMap does not
  if (Map.isMap(object)) {
    return object;
    // ^^^ FLOW ERROR: object type This type is incompatible with the expected return type of Map
  }

  return Map(object);
};
```

After checking that `Map.isMap(object)`, I know that the object is a Map, but Flow doesn't. Why not? Is there some way I can 'inform' Flow that it's now a map?

Possible sub-question: is there actually any advantage to using `Map.isMap(obj)` as opposed to `obj instanceof Map`? (If not, why do they offer the static method?)

---

EDIT: looking at [Immutable's own typedef](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/6a50e0d6876b3af7a809b1a6dd647e78830fa4d5/dist/immutable.js.flow#L684) it seems to have some interesting `%checks` syntax to address the very issue I'm having, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. And I can't find docs on it.

```
declare function isMap(maybeMap: mixed): boolean %checks(maybeMap instanceof Map);
```

Comment: Are you sure it is picking up the definitions for `immutable` properly? Like if you import something that doesn't exist, does that error as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question...

It looks like the problem is the `%checks` hasn't been released in Immutable yet. Latest stable version 3.8.1 [doesn't have it](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/v3.8.1/dist/immutable.js.flow#L471).

Also it doesn't seem to be in Flow stable yet (as of v0.45).

Comment: I've created the issue on that https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/1278